# unlocking threads only on new data (threads calling order)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking, getter-setter

so i have a class like:

```
class mySafeData
{
public:
    void Set(int i) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
        myData = i;
    }
    void Get( int& i)
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
        i = myData;
    }
private:
    int myData;
    boost::mutex myMutex;

};
```

I have some thread that calls `Set` in loop and 3 threads that call `Get` in a loop. I need to make my threads `Get` one peace of data not more than once (meaning it can not call `Get` as fast as we `Set` it and that is OK but it shall not call it more than once unteel new `Set` was called). I mean after thread called `Get` it shall not gain access to `Get` unteel `Set` was executed. How to implement such thing into such simple class or will my lock do it for me by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [condition variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref).

Note that even when your reader thread acquires the mutex associated with condition variable, it needs to check the condition has been met. Perhaps let the setter set a flag when it has set something and the reader can reset it when it has read it.

This needs refinement but will do the job. I would generally use a std::deque so the writer can write having to lock but without having to wait for a thread to read it.

```
class mySafeData
{
public:
  mySafeData() : myData(0), changed( false )
  {
  }

  void Set(int i) 
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
    while( changed )
        myCondvar.wait( lock ); // wait for the data to be read

    myData = i; // set the data
    changed = true; // mark as changed
    myCondvar.notify_one(); // notify so a reader can process it
  }

  void Get( int& i)
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
    while( !changed )
    {
       myCondvar.wait( lock );
    } 
    i = myData;
    changed = false; // mark as read
    myCondvar.notify_one(); // notify so the writer can write if necessary
  }
 private:
   int myData;
   boost::mutex myMutex;
   boost::condition_variable myCondvar;
   bool changed;
};
```

Comment: We have lots of readers so I need some king of one flag for tham all. and if reader had no time to read what was Seted it is OK .

Comment: I have done an implementation that ensures every set gets read. If you don't require that and you can just write over an unread value, then the Set() function above does not need to wait on the condition variable, and the Get() function does not need to signal it.

Comment: hm... When we set  changed = false; // mark as read for one reader thread wouldnt it set it for all other readers? I mean wouldnt it happen so that only one reader would get data?

Comment: when we set changed = false it will be marked as read so all the readers will know it is read and only one would actually "Get" it. "changed" here is reflecting a state of the class.

Comment: and how to make all readers to be capable or reading data (but only once a Set)? you can post an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713357/would-such-class-be-readable-only-once-a-set-by-multiple-threads

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [conditional variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) to signal the change in state of the object to the other threads.

Comment: you mean we can not implement waiting on this class level but only on level where we create threads? or if it can be dne on this class level please provide some code more related to a sample I provided - (sorry i am threading nube)