# Would such class be readable only once a Set by multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, boost, locking

So having a class like:

```
class mySafeData
{
public:
  mySafeData() : myData(0), changed( false )
  {
  }

  void Set(int i) 
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
    myData = i; // set the data
    changed = true; // mark as changed
    myCondvar.notify_one(); // notify so a reader can process it
  }

  void Get( int& i)
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
    while( !changed )
    {
       myCondvar.wait( lock );
    } 
    i = myData;
    changed = false; // mark as read
    myCondvar.notify_one(); // notify so the writer can write if necessary
  }
 private:
   int myData;
   boost::mutex myMutex;
   boost::condition_variable myCondvar;
   bool changed;
};
```

And one thread in loop calling `Set`. And 3 or more threads calling `Get` how to make all threads calling `Get` to actually get data (each thread shall `Get` data only once a `Set` was called)(it seems like only first "reader" who calls `Get` gets data)?

update will this do?:

```
class mySafeData
{
public:
  mySafeData() : myData(0)
  {
  }

  void Set(int i) 
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
    myData = i; // set the data
  }

  void Get( int& i)
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
    i = myData;

  }
 private:
   int myData;
   boost::mutex myMutex;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, It's an odd approach to call `notify_one()` in the reader (`Get`)! If you want your readers to wait till something has been set, then you need something like this:

```
 void Set(int i) 
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
    myData = i; // set the data
    ++stateCounter;  // some int to track state chages
    myCondvar.notify_all(); // notify all readers
  }

  void Get( int& i)
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
    // copy the current state
    int cState = stateCounter;
    // waits for a notification and change of state
    while (stateCounter == cState)
      myCondvar.wait( lock );
  }
```

Now a call to `Get` will effectively wait till there is a valid change of state. However this approach (with conditions) is prone to issues such as spurious wakeups (which should be handled by the loop), lost notifications etc. You need to find a better model for this (all most sounds like a case of a queue per thread).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need the condition variable; the mutex ought to be enough.

Also, the `changed` variable isn't helping you; it's only allowing one thread to see the change.  Remove that as well.

Comment: I updated post - do you mean that update I posted will work? My main point is for readers not to read more than once on one set...

Comment: I imagine that would work (although you probably need to declare `myData` as `volatile` to prevent the compiler making unsafe optimisations.  I'm not sure what you mean by "reads not to read more than once on each set".  Surely you just want `get()` to safely return the most recent value each time a reader thread calls it?

Comment: I tried to explain here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713782/boost-mutex-order